# Why std::bitset::reference::operator~?

Tags: c++, std, standards, bitset

I was reading the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference) of `std::bitset` and I was wondering why `std::bitset::reference` explicitly define `operator~` because I don't see any performance or design reasons. Without it, I think it would work equally well:

```
bool b = ~mybitset[i];
```

because the reference would be converted to a bool, on which the `~` operator would be applied.

Any explanation for this design decision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bool b = true;
b = ~b;
```

The value of `b` after this operation is `true`!

This is because `~` promotes the `bool` to `int` of value 1, then performs the bitwise-not on the result, which resolves to -2, and then casts that back to `bool` which is true.

So it has to provide an operator so that the result is how you would expect it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the integral promotions, `~true` is `~1`, which is most assuredly nonzero, and hence not `false`, when converted back to `bool`.